# Creating pointer to function instead of object when instentiating with parenthesis

Tags: c++, object, function-pointers, instantiation

```
#include<iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
    int qux(int x);
};

int Foo::qux(int x)
{
    return 2 * x;
}

int main()
{
    Foo foo();
    int a = foo.qux(4);
}
```

displays the error

```
Error : expression must have class type but it has type "Foo (*)()"
```

It would work if I don't use the parenthesis when instantiating foo. But it should also instantiate the object with parenthesis at the end right? Why does it create a function pointer?

Comment: Congratulations on hitting the Most Vexing Parse (as the duplicate explains more).  Also investigate [Uniform Initialization](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp11-language#uniform-init) since that's what you want for your objects.  Welcome to C++.

Comment: @KevinAnderson, thanks for the reference, vexing indeed

Comment: @KevinAnderson “Uniform” is a lie (due to initialiser lists) and many C++ experts consider it a mistake in hindsight. It certainly won’t avoid initialisation fubar, so I no longer use (nor recommend) it universally. Instead, I now advocate for “always auto”. It’s the best way in C++ of avoiding unexpected initialisation behaviour.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Oh I absolutely agree that the name is a misnomer, but "starting from there" is a rather good thing IMO, and like it or not, "Uniform" is in the "official" name of that.  Start with a generally OK thing, then finding out its limitations is a decent way to learn.  The virtues of "always auto" are many, but it also has drawbacks that make it not "universal" either, but that's a different topic.

Comment: @KevinAnderson actually I think I was confused because of the notation  `MyClass* object = new MyClass();` which create a pointer to an object initialized to zero

Comment: @KevinAnderson The issue with “starting from there” is that it does the wrong/unexpected thing by default. For instance, you *must not* use uniform initialisation with generic code (`T{args}`) unless you actually want to invoke the initialiser list constructor. That’s why I’ve reverted to using `()` by default: it always works, does the correct/expected thing, and with Always Auto it never triggers MVP.